# Как вернуть нативный цвет svg иконки?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, svg

Добрый день, можно ли вернуть стандартный цвет иконки?
Если svg закидываю через тег svg цвет отображается должным образом, 
но я пропихиваю иконку только через use, не кидаю ее в телом куском svg

```
mixin icon(name)
  svg(class="icon icon_" + name)&attributes(attributes)
    use(xlink:href=config.path.images + "/icons.svg#" + name)
```

тогда иконка заливается одним цветом, как это исправить?
Выше иконка пропихивается через use, нижний вариант так как есть, те помещаю тег svg в тело документа.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как только вы используете команду `use` объект попадает в shadow DOM и стилизация иконки не работает.  Для того, чтобы устранить эту проблему необходимо:

1. Удалить в коде иконки все атрибуты стилизации у патчей, полигонов и
   т.д все инлайновые стили - `fill`, `stroke`
2. Добавить в таблице стилей `path{ fill:inherit; stroke:inherit; }`
3. Стилизацию иконок уже делать в таблице стилей на уровне классов иконок
4. В шапку файлов иконок добавить строчку, указывающую на внешнюю
   таблицу стилей
   `<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>`

   5. Файл таблицы стилей и файлы SVG лучше разместить в одной папке, так как браузеры чувствительны к этому, больше других `chrome`

Comment: Но ведь если сделать `fill: inherit`, то вроде как и убирать атрибуты не нужно (1 пункт).

Comment: @ Sasha Omelchenko инлайновые атрибуты имеют наивысший приоритет их не перешибить ничем, проверял :) Да и статьи имеются на этот счет - например той же Сары Сауендал

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0yhLphd7/ ну вроде как работает даже с атрибутом ) или если свг в отдельный файл поместить, то перестанет?

Comment: @ Да, автор же пишет, что использует  иконки через use, чтобы не копировать куски svg  А про высший приоритет инлайновых свойств это касается чисто svg файлов и таблиц стилей, что внутри файла <style></style>и  что во внешней таблице стилей, все они проигрывают стилям в патчах

Comment: Поэтому и удалять нужно инлайновые стили svg и принудительно наследовать сверху кстати по этой же причине спрайты при варке  удаляют инлайновые стили файлов svg

Comment: @Sasha Omelchenko кстати в своем примере поменяй fill="orange" на style="fil:orange;" и увидешь, что ничем не перешибить оранжевый цвет, вот это и есть наивысший приоритет

Comment: Ага, ну собственно мой вопрос был про атрибуты, так что вы правы.

Comment: Скинте пожалуйста пример на фидл что бы при использовании use сохранился родной цвет иконки, без всяких заливок.

Comment: @Anton Essential скинь коды своих иконок с ними пример сделаю

Comment: @Alexandr_T Куда мне их скинуть?

Comment: @Anton Essential так прямо в свой вопрос добавьте код иконки, обычно так и делают, если хотят получить конкретную помощь

Comment: @Anton Essential вижу, что иконка сделана в incsape, но зачем у "id" русский текст. Иконка, как отдельный файл SVG не работает. Её надо переделывать - убирать русский текст, оптимизировать.  Если хотите переделаю, но надо будет подождать. Посмотрите - аналогичный случай в соседнем топике - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/649996/28748

Comment: @Alexandr_T Спасибо, не не стоит, их там много иконок ))